# jQuery overall element index

Tags: jquery, indexing

http://api.jquery.com/index/

Is there a way to use jQuery `index()` method to find the index of an element related to the overall document?

I mean, if I have a bunch of img tags in a document, is there a way to know, regardless of their position in the document, their index?

example :

```
<body>
<img />
<div>
   <img />
   <div>
      <img />
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I've tried using $(window), $(body), $(document), but they all fail. I really need the overall index of the element.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index() returns the position in a given collection:

```
$('img').index('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
$('img').index(imgElement);
```

or

```
$('*').index(imgElement);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

$('*').index($('.someClass'))

Comment: that can be tricky if the class exists in more than one element.